# In QT C++ while am editing Qtable model data i need to get a small box and in that i need to show the editing text how is it possible?

Tags: c++, qt

```
tmodel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
tmodel->setTable("trainee_info");
tmodel->select();
```

by this we will get a table model as output and it can be editable but while editing i need to show a label below the field in which am trying to edit and text should populate in it . so how can i do that.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using a `QStandardItemModel` you have to set the item editable before adding to the model, like the code below:

```
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

Then, when you will double click on the item it would open a line edit by default for editing.

For finer controls you can also install a delegate on your table and override the `createEditor` function.

```
QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & /*inOption*/, const QModelIndex & inIndex ) const override
{
   auto editor = new QLineEdit( parent );
   return editor;
}
```

this will give you a line edit to edit your model.

But your case is pretty simple and the first approach will work for you!

Comment: thanks for reply ,,,, but am using Qsqltablemodel
..i.e                       traineemodel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    traineemodel->setTable("trainee_info");
    traineemodel->select();
    traineemodel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit); after this am trying to display the it. so to this present code wt changes i can make? can u pls give a simple example such that i can understand more easyly becoz am really new to this Qt c++. ....

Comment: What is the type of the table? QTableView or QTableWidget?

Comment: ui->tableView_2->setModel(trainee_info); its QTableModel

Comment: Acutually Prime its like this ...in windows if we are trying to type something in search box we will get a label  which flows our text with search icon so i want the similar kind of thing in Qt i.e while am editing a field in tableview i just want to get the same text which am typing in a new label which can be a popup or a scroll down label...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you intend to achieve, it is not completely clear from your description! Some sort of mock up of GUI for a better understanding. Also please update your question with all this info else no one wwill be able to help!